# Singly linked list max key searching

Tags: java, search, singly-linked-list

I have created this Node class and i want to find the node with the biggest key and return it:

```
class Node{
    int key;
    Node next;
    Node(int x){ key = x; next = null; 
    }
    int max = 0;


    Node findmax(Node h){
        if(h==null) return null;

        int max = 0;
        Node t= null;
        for(t=h; t!=null; t=t.next){
            if(t.next.key>t.key) max=t.next.key;
            t=t.next;
        }
        return t;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node a = new Node(0);
        Node b = new Node(5);
        Node c = new Node(12);
        Node d = new Node(-12);
        Node e = new Node(124);
        Node f = new Node(2321);
        Node g = new Node(-231);

        findmax(a);

    }

}
```

Any idea why i keep geeting this compile error:

Node.java:34: error: non-static method findmax(Node) cannot be        referenced from a static context
    findmax(a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Node findNode()
{   
    Node node = nodeList.getHead(); // get the head of the list
    Node prev = null;               // stores the previous node


    while(node != null)
    {   
        if(prev != null && prev.getKey() > node.getKey())
        {
            Node maxNode = prev;
        }

        // store node as prev and get the next node
        prev = node;
        node = node.getNext();
     }

return maxNode;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add the `static` modifier to `findMax`:

```
static Node findmax(Node h) { ... }
```

---

Your method will still not work because all the nodes are disconnected. You can connect them with `a.next = b`, `b.next = c`, etc. Also, you never actually return the maximum node:

```
static Node findmax(Node h){
    if(h == null) return null;

    Node max = h;

    Node t;
    for(t = h; t.next != null; t = t.next){
        if(t.key > max.key)
            max = t;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Node findmax(Node head){
    Node max;
    while (head.hasNext()){

    }
}
```

Comment: I just did that and this comes up:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Node.findmax(Node.java:18)
 at Node.main(Node.java:34)

Comment: did you check the `next` value is `!=null`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `findMax(Node)` isn't static.

To fix this, you can make it static:

```
public static Node findMax(Node head) {
   ...  
}
```

However, as you have this code written it will always just find the node you pass in, because you never set any `next` pointers anywhere.

Another option is to implement it as a method on a `Node` and assume the node you are calling is the head node...

```
public Node findMax() {
    Node head = this;
    // etc...
}
```

And finally, this implementation is buggy in that you will get a `NullPointerException` if you pass in a single `Node`:

```
 Node t= null;
 for(t=h; t!=null; t=t.next) {
    // If t.next == null, the next line will fail.
    // You check for t != null for the loop condition, but not t.next != null
    if(t.next.key>t.key) max=t.next.key; 
    t=t.next;
 }
```

Comment: can you give me a quote about what to do?